# Does it make sense to always use a singleton when there is only one instance needed?

Tags: java, swing, singleton, parameter-passing

So in my case I have a `JTextArea` initialized in my `UserInterface` class. Now if I want to put messages into this `outputField` from other classes I dont know exaclty how I should approch this.

**My first idea was this:**

To pass the `outputField` variable to each class, who needs to output something and than set the output via a `outpufield.append`.
But somehow I dont know if this is a clean approach to pass this variable to each object.

**Another idea I came up with:**

Make a singleton instance of the `UserInterface` class and call it with a `getUserInterface()` method from within each class that needs it. From there I could just use `JTextArea outputField = UserInterface.getGUI().getOutputArea();`.

Are there even better approaches or which of mine ideas is a cleaner way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: M-V-C design pattern. Have appropriate classes update your model, and have the UserInterface observe the model for changes, and update its state accordingly.

Comment: Okay I could redisign pretty fast because I am not that far in my project yet. There is another question that came up tho:

In case im adding `KeyListener`s to my gui elements. They automatically have to call methods from the Controller element. But the View should not need to know about the Controller as far as I understood the MVC concept.

How do I approach this generally?

Comment: When I've done MVC, my goals have been to 1) make the view as dumb as possible and 2) craft the model so that it is view-agnostic, that it doesn't need to know about the view and can work with any type of view that I throw at it. Note that I'm not a pro, and you'll perhaps want to wait for their replies. Also as a side issue, generally you will want to favor [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over KeyListeners.

Comment: Add a simple setter like method in your user interface (or better in model if you implement MVC) : `public void setText(String txt) { /*todo  update txt to outpufield*/ }`

Comment: But then I still need a instance of the `UserInterface` in the other classes.